# Importar algumas colunas do TXT para VBA

Tags: vba, txt, importação

Boa tarde!

Sou bem iniciante e estou com dúvidas de como prosseguir. Eu tenho um TXT e consegui importar ele pra VBA e até conseguir tirar a primeira linha que não precisava.

Porém, preciso refazer e apenas importar 5 colunas que me interessam, já que a planilha vai de A até a coluna GI.

E ainda por cima preciso ter a primeira linha com o nome que darei para as 5 colunas importadas. Isso é possível e como eu faria isso?

O código que usei:

```
Sub importar_arquivo()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    importaArquivo
End Sub

Private Function importaArquivo()
    Dim arquivo As String
    arquivo = abrirArquivo
    If arquivo <> Empty Then
        Debug.Print "ok"
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add 'nova planilha
        With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;" & arquivo & "", Destination:=Range("A1"))
            .Name = "teste"
            .FieldNames = True
            .RowNumbers = False
            .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
            .PreserveFormatting = True
            .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
            .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
            .SavePassword = False
            .SaveData = True
            .AdjustColumnWidth = True
            .RefreshPeriod = 0
            .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
            .TextFilePlatform = 850
            .TextFileStartRow = 2
            .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
            .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
            .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
            .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
            .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
            .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
            .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
            .TextFileOtherDelimiter = "|"
            .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
            .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
            .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        End With
    End If
    arquivo = ""
End Function

Function abrirArquivo() As String
    Dim arquivo As String
    On Error GoTo sair:
    arquivo = ""
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
          'Selecção de apenas um aquivo
          .AllowMultiSelect = False
          'Filtro de extenção
          .Filters.Add "All files", "*.txt; *.csv"
          'Mostra a caixa de dialogo
          .Show
          'Armazena o caminho do arquivo
          arquivo = .SelectedItems.Item(1)
    End With
    abrirArquivo = arquivo
sair:
    arquivo = ""
End Function
```

E o código que preciso fazer é pegar apenas o que deixei em negrito na primeira linha.

```
[H2]1|2|||10|49.92|1818481.6|0|S0011||||||||||||S0011|||||||||||||**51**|20201030000000||20201030000000|||||||||||||**2**||||||988788|9770|**9770**|||||||0|0|0||||False|**UNITS**|**12**||||20250220000000|||||||12|12|0|6|988788||||||||||0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|||||||||||||||||||||0|0|0|0|0||||||||||||||||||||||||
```

Abraços,

Arthur Esteves

Comment: Qual é o código inicial utilizado?, qual é o problema, você tentou algum código?

Comment: O código que usei funcionou, porém é o básico mesmo. Eu preciso pegar algumas colunas do TXT apenas. E não todo o arquivo como eu fiz. e ainda tenho que acrescer uma primeira linha definindo o nome que preciso.

Comment: Qual código?...

Comment: Não cabe o código aqui

Comment: você tem que montar um exemplo minimo de código e exemplo do arquivo, dessa forma não vejo como responder

Comment: editei a pergunta e coloquei.